# How to return filename without any extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code below to get the filename from the url, but when there is a # and number, it doest not work completely. How can i just get  the filename so that it only returns "somefilename" or "somename"  ? some examples of  various scenarios

Fileformats examples

```
     1. www.something.com/somefilename.html#108
or
     2. www.someting.com/group//somename.shtml
or
     3. www.something.com/group/somename#1011
```

Jasvascript

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var url=window.location.href;
     var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     alert(" filename " +filename);
     var cleanfilename =filename.slice(0, -5)
     alert(" cleanfilename" +cleanfilename);
    alert($('#business-type :selected').val());
    $('select[id^="business-type"] option[value='+cleanfilename+']').attr("selected","selected");


    });
```

Comment: Rather than using the full `href`, consider starting your search using one of the other `location` properties, such as `window.location.pathname` - that gets rid of the querystring and location fragments for you.  You just need to strip the "extension", if present, off the end then.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `substring`, and `lastIndexOf` functions. Like:

Example Input:

```
var link = "www.something.com/somefilename.html#108"
```

Code:

```
link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, link.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Output:

```
"somefilename"
```

**Edit:**

If links are like `www.something.com/somefilename.html#108/5.2`, then following might help:

```
var linkWithoutHash = link.substring(0, link.lastIndexOf("#"));
var fileName = linkWithoutHash.substring(linkWithoutHash .lastIndexOf("/") + 1, linkWithoutHash .lastIndexOf("."));
console.log(fileName);
```

Comment: `location.hash` can contain slashes and dots as well ("...filename.html#108/5.2"), so this approach is not bulletproof.

Comment: @myf thanks for explanation. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I vote to @MuhammadImran, since this works if file name has several dots.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for

```
var filename = document.location.pathname.match(/([^/]*?)(?:\..*)?$/)[1]
```

Comment: pretty perfect! It does all of what OP required. But maybe it could even be improved to deal with cases where there is an extra dot in the file name ( before the one with the extension): `var filename = document.location.pathname.match(/([^/]*?)(?:\.[^.]*)?$/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in only two lines of code:

```
var a = location.pathname.split("/").pop();
a.substring(0, a.indexOf('.'));
```

`.split("/").pop()` retrieves the portion of the URL after the last `/`, excluding the hash (`#`) or the search (`?`) attributes

`.substring(0, a.indexOf('.'));` removes everything after the `.`, removing the file extension.

On my machine, this process took a total of 0.092ms, whereas an approach that uses regex took 0.253ms. If this minute timing difference is not important to you, then using regex is slightly shorter and simpler overall.

Answer (score 0):

**My simple idea:**

- Split the file path into array of chars
- Iterate backwards, accumulate each character as the filename
- As long as it sees `.` or `#`, reset the filename to empty string
- Once hits a `/`, just end

Here we go:

```
var paths = [ 'www.something.com/somefilename.html#108',
        'www.someting.com/group//somename.shtml',
        'www.something.com/group/somename#1011',
        'ftp://somewhere.somedot/f/f/name',
        'ftp://somewhere.somedot/var1/var2/filename.dot.dot',
        'dir/naked_filename.etc'];

function extractName(s){
    var chars = s.split('');
    var c = chars.pop();
    var filename = '';
    while (c!='/' && chars.length>0){
        if (c=='#' || c=='.') filename = '';
        else filename = c + filename;
        c = chars.pop();
    }
    return filename;
}

console.log( paths.map(extractName) );
// [ "somefilename", "somename", "somename", "name", "filename", "naked_filename"]
```

Answer (score -1):

The below instructions will work for all the files of these type:

```
www.something.com/somefilename.html#108
www.someting.com/group//somename.shtml
www.something.com/group/somename#1011
```

Let's say we'll do this:

1. Assuming the file name is stored in this variable:

   ```
   var filename = "www.something.com/somefilename.html#108";
   ```
2. Get the file name part. So, we need to get the last item of the /.

   ```
   filename = filename.split("/");
   filename = filename[filename.length - 1]; // Get the last one.
   ```
3. Now to split it with `#`, irrespective of whether it has the character or not and get the first one.

   ```
   filename = filename.split("#");
   filename = filename[0]; // Get the first one.
   ```
4. Now get the filename without the extension:

   ```
   filename = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1);
   filename = filename[0]; // Get the filename.
   ```

The complete function will be:

```
function getFilename (filename) {
    filename = filename.split("/");
    filename = filename[filename.length - 1];
    filename = filename.split("#");
    filename = filename[0];
    filename = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1);
    filename = filename[0];
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: I tried this with the example URL you provided in your answer, and it returned "s". :(

Comment: same here i just got and "r" not the file name